# people deleting other users inputs in excel, how to prevent it?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel, vba

In my company we have an excel spreadsheet with 8 different vehicles for 20 something managers. Currently the spreadsheet is a little cumbersome and I'm looking to stream line the process. The main issue is certain people like to delete a person's checkout of a vehicle and put their own name and time. Is there a way to make an excel spreadsheet shareable but yet not be able to change or remove inputs from other users? I know outlook calendar is a good option to show check outs but it still won't fix the deleting of other people's checkout issue. Sharepoint is not an option for us since it is not available for us to download on our work computers. This also has to be in a monthly calendar and time format. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Sheets can be password protected - consider a sheet for each user where each user has a password for their sheet.  Then a summary sheet which combines each user's sheet.  Use formulas to limit options on each user's sheet.

Comment: Or similar, have a read-only sheet with all the info (perhaps dropdowns would be handy to select vehicle etc...) and a user form to add info with no delete - for delete they have to see the sheet-master...

Comment: All the above suggestions are solid, My personal favourite for shared sheets is telling the user that they can only enter data using inserted lines, they then reduce the risk of saving over each other... Track changes means you can see who has been saving over other peoples data so you can name and shame if required (or send a gentle e-mail covering the need to insert a new line)

Answer (score 0):

why don't you transport the Spreadsheet to a SharePoint list?,